# i want to convert my php-script to js. please

Tags: php, javascript

I wrote a script in php. It's very simple, it just multiplies a typed in number and adds another number to it. But I don't know how to convert it to js.

From the form on my html page, I submit the kilometers and the script calculates the cost of this ride (it's a taxi company).

```
<form action="http://www.mydomain.de/action.php" class="box style" method="post" target="_blank">

<fieldset>
    <legend>Jetzt berechnen:</legend>
    <div style="float: left;"><label for="km">KM-Eingabe</label> <input name="km" type="Text"></div><div><input src="/images/berechnen.png" alt="berechnen" type="image"></div>
</fieldset>

</form>
```

The php script is this:

```
<p>
Sie haben angegeben, dass die geplante Fahrt <?php echo $_POST["km"];?> km betr&auml;gt.
<br />
Im  Tagtarif (werktags 06-22 Uhr) kostet die angefragte Fahrt <?php $km=$_POST["km"]; echo $km * 1.7 + 2.2; ?> EURO.
<br />
Im Nachttarif / Sonn- und Feiertags (werktags 22-06 Uhr) kostet die angefragte Fahrt <?php $km=$_POST["km"]; echo $km * 1.8 + 2.2;?> EURO.
</p>
```

Comment: It's not possible to retrieve `POST` values using JavaScript.

Comment: how can i do than the multiply of it

Comment: Language issue in the PHP coding section.

Comment: no, the php coding works fine. i just needed the js-version of this php-script. and i didn't try already but i hope, it'll work, what mike posted here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably learn the basics of Javascript, but hopefully this will help you get started

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Jetzt berechnen:</legend>
    <div style="float: left;"><label for="km">KM-Eingabe</label> <input id="txt_km" type="Text"></div><div><input src="/images/berechnen.png" alt="berechnen" type="image" onclick="submit()" /></div>
</fieldset>

<div id="resultDiv" style="display: none;">
   <p>
       Sie haben angegeben, dass die geplante Fahrt <span id="km"></span> km betr&auml;gt.
   <br />
       Im  Tagtarif (werktags 06-22 Uhr) kostet die angefragte Fahrt <span id="result"></span> EURO.
   <br />
   Im Nachttarif / Sonn- und Feiertags (werktags 22-06 Uhr) kostet die angefragte Fahrt <span id="result2" /> EURO.
   </p>
</div>

<script>
   function submit()
   {
       var km = parseInt(document.getElementById('txt_km').value);
       document.getElementById('km').innerHTML = km;
       document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = km * 1.7 + 2.2;
       document.getElementById('result2').innerHTML = km * 1.8 + 2.2;
       document.getElementById('resultDiv').style.display = '';
   }
</script>
```

Comment: ok i need some more help. how can i format the results? i want , instead of . when it goes over from euro to cents. and i want the results to show always the cents and always 2 decs. thank you